# Javascript timer running in react-native stops when we present a Native module

Tags: objective-c, react-native

Running a react-native app, I have a timer that is supposed to kick a user out of a checkout flow if it runs out. When we present an apple pay view we are creating an instance of a javascript class that exposes a `show` method which triggers a native `viewController`. When the apple pay controller is presented, the timer in the background stops. Is there a way to do this without pausing the JS thread. Here is the `viewController` that mounts: [ReactNativePayments.m](https://github.com/naoufal/react-native-payments/blob/master/packages/react-native-payments/lib/ios/ReactNativePayments.m)